# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Tags: python

I am receiving this error (`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'`) when trying to run this code

```
total_exams = 0
for total_exams in range(1, 100001):
    sum += total_exams
print(sum)

sum = 0
total_exams = 0
while count <= 100000:
    sum += total_exams
    total_exams += 1
print(sum)

sum = int("Please enter Exam grade, or press 999 to end: ")
while true:
    if sum <= 100:
        sum += total_exams
        total_exams += 1
    elif sum == "999":
        print(sum / total_exams)
```

over all I just need to run the program until 999 is entered, and then find the average of all the numbers entered. At least a little help will be nice.

So i have edited my code to (new)

```
totalExams = 0
total_sum = 0
for totalExams in range (1, 100001):
    total_sum += totalExams
print(total_sum)

total_sum = 0
totalExams = 0
while totalExams <= 100000:
    total_sum += totalExams
    totalExams += 1
print(total_sum)

exam_sum = int("Please enter Exam grade, or press 999 to end: ")
while true:
    if exam_sum <= 100:
        exam_sum += totalExams
        totalExams += 1
    elif exam_sum == "999":
        print(exam_sum / totalExams)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Python33/vfvfv.py", line 14, in 
    exam_sum = int("Please enter Exam grade, or press 999 to end: ")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Please enter Exam grade, or press 999 to end: '

Comment: To your last edit: you forgot `if` and an `:` after elif. However, you should overwrite `sum` right before you use it. Also notice that you should at least invest some time understanding what you're doing and especially _reading_ the error message. Most of the time it points out the exact line where the error occurred.

Comment: Your code is really really broken.

Comment: This isn't going to work: `sum = int("Please enter Exam grade, or press 999 to end: ")`

Comment: The code does not make any sense…

Answer (score 11):

Here is an answer to one of you problems, however it won't help you that much, since your code is quite broken…

`sum` is a built-in function, just like `len` for example. Use another name and you're fine ;-)

**Further explanation:**

In this line

```
sum += totalExams
```

you're doing

```
sum = sum + totalExams
```

where `totalExams` has type `int` and `sum` is a built-in function in python. Since the `+` operator is not implemented for `int` and `built-in-function`, you get a `TypeError`. (`sum` was not redefined before, so it's pointing to the function.)

You can solve it by simply choosing a variable name which is not already used, like `total_sum` or `sum_exams` etc.:

```
sum_exams += totalExams
```

Or simply declare it before you use it:

```
sum = 0
```

Caveat: doing so, you'll overwrite the built-in function `sum()`.

**More problems:**

Here, you're casting a `string` to an `int`, which absolutely does not make a sense:

```
exam_sum = int("Please enter Exam grade, or press 999 to end: ")
```

I guess you're trying to get some input from the user and cast it to an integer? In this case, you should use `input()`:

```
exam_sum = input("Please enter Exam grade, or press 999 to end: ")
```

**And before you edit your question again, the next error will be**

```
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

`True` is what you want…

**Last but not least**

After all these fixes you'll end up with an infinite loop. Now sit back and think about your code before asking the next question.

Comment: Don't forget `exam_sum == "999":`

Answer (score -1):

You have not defined `sum` before your first loop. If you add

```
sum = 0
```

it will work fine.

However, you probably want to use a different variable name so you are not overriding the built in function.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get the user to enter the number, you might have meant int(input(...))