# Unsupported operand type for builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python

I have a problem with my code. I need to create a code that says if the number entered is even or odd. The code is

```
print ("enter a number")
a = input
if a% 2 == 0:
    print ("even")
else:
    print ("odd")
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type (s) for%: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

What should I change?

Thank you.

Comment: You're not *calling* the input function.

Comment: Ciao Riccardo, non se parla molto italiano qui, ma piutosto inglese :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19061250/608639, https://stackoverflow.com/q/19421688/608639, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'builtin\_function\_or\_method' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421688/unsupported-operand-types-for-builtin-function-or-method-and-int)

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the input into integer first.